# Многомодульный gradle проект без корневого проекта

Tags: java, gradle

Один из наших основных проектов переехал на java и gradle. Мои знания в этой области невелики, поэтому нужна помощь знатоков в организации структуры проекта как для разработки, так и для деплоя

Что имеем:

- Несколько библиотек общего кода, каждая в отдельном репозитории
- Несколько исполняемых модулей, зависящих от общих библиотек, и также каждый в своём репозитории

то есть сейчас что-то вроде:

```
/common
    build.gradle
        plugins {id 'java-library'}
    /src
        /main
            /java
                ...
/kit
    build.gradle
        plugins {id 'java-library'}
    /src
        /main
            /java
                ...
/module1
    build.gradle
        plugins {
            id 'java'
            id 'application'
        }
        dependencies {common, kit}
    /src
        /main
            /java
                ...
/module2
    build.gradle
        plugins {
            id 'java'
            id 'application'
        }
        dependencies {common, kit}
    /src
        /main
            /java
                ...
```

Если для исполняемых модулей создавать верхнеуровневый проект, то всё собирается и запускается:

```
moduleBuilder1
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
        include 'common'
        include 'kit'
    /common
        ...
    /kit
        ...
    /module1
        ...
```

Проблема в том, что таких moduleBuilder-ов нужно несколько, и мы не можем в каждый из них пихать отдельную копию исходников библиотек. То есть вариант верхнеуровневого проекта в принципе не подходит.

Другой вариант - это собирать либы отдельным запуском, а в build.gradle модулей прописывать зависимости от конкретных jar файлов извне (тоже не совсем понял, как это правильно делать). Минус этого подхода - что пересборке модуля пересборка библиотеки осуществляться не будет, и если я что-то изменил в библиотеке и руками её не пересобрал, модуль этих изменений не увидит.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вообще в мире java принято организовывать подобные задачи?

И следом вытекающий вопрос: как затем посредством gradle организовать деплой исполняемых модулей с прилинкованными библиотеками на продакшн? В идеале при деплое я хочу создавать некие установочные пакеты OS (например, для ubuntu будет module1.deb и module2.deb), в которые будут сложены все необходимые артефакты сборки модулей module1 и module2. Что и откуда брать и какие команды gradle выполнять? Если у кого-то есть опыт решения подобных задач, поделитесь пожалуйста.

Comment: Ответ найден: использовать композитную сборку (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html)